# Does hibernate transaction isolation level affect JBoss datasource isolaiton level?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions

My Hibernate refers to uses a no-tx-datasource JBoss datasource. The transaction isolation level is defined in hibernate.cfg. Does the transaction isolation level need to be defined to the JBoss datasource too? It feels like the transaction isolation level works different compared to only using hibernate directly. With the no-tx-datasource, it looks like two opened transactions in code can read each others changes (as in READ_UNCOMMITTED) but with only hibernate, transactions are fully isolated from each other (READ_COMMITTED).